# Массив или не массив?

Tags: php

Вырываю кусок кода из одного ПО:

```
$parts = explode("||", $db_result['content']);

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $blocks = explode('|', $part);
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($blocks); $i++) {
        $param = explode(' ', $blocks[$i]);
        $this->structure[$blocks[0]][$param[0]][weight]     = $param[1];
        $this->structure[$blocks[0]][$param[0]][name]       = $param[2];
        $this->structure[$blocks[0]][$param[0]][permission] = $param[3];
        $this->structure[$blocks[0]][$param[0]][design]     = $param[4];
        $this->structure[$blocks[0]][$param[0]][parameter]  = $param[5];
    }
}
```

В данном коде structure - это свойство одного класса. Не могу понять, что означает эта надпись:

```
  $this->structure[$blocks[0]][$param[0]][weight]=$param[1];
```

Вроде как НЕ массив... объясните, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: вот эти weight, name, permission, design, parameter - константы?

Comment: При обращении к массиву по ключу, ключ можно не заключать в кавычки. Выяснил только что опытным путем =) Может быть от настроек php зависит, но у меня работает:

    $test = array(
        "key" => "value",
        "key2" => "value2",
    );
    echo $test[key2]; // выводить value2

Comment: @gridsane, не болтайте ерундой (с)

[Почему $foo[bar] неверно?](http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Comment: Оу. Буду знать. Раньше даже не думал об этом - всегда кавычки использовал =)

Comment: а всегда и надо, если не хотите потом сума сходить почему код фентеля выдаёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@GoodSpeed](/users/6156/goodspeed)](/users/6156/goodspeed) - это массив, с чего вы взяли что это *не массив?*. Собственно у вас, в примере, все примерно *[вот так вот](http://codepad.org/6JJt6JXs)*. С той лишь разницей, что массив - это поле класса.

Ну а то, что для обращения к ключам не используются кавычки - это уже быдлокод ^_^

Comment: Благодарю. Просто где-то слышал, что если не ставится кавычка (либо одинарная), то это не массив а что-то другое...как оказалось - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Это трехмерный массив:

```
  $this->structure[$blocks[0]][$param[0]][weight]=$param[1];
```

Чтобы представить, как он устроен, вспомните куб и три его измерения.

Comment: Вспомнил, спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Эммм... лучше кавычки ставить.. и при этом - одинарные :) 
Блин, Вы error.log откройте, там же куча Ворнингов, навеное, у Вас собралась :D

Comment: Посмотрел - ничего нет) Странно это конечно...правда я назначил свой обработчик ошибок и сделал, чтобы мелкие ошибки и warning'и не записывались в лог.

Comment: @GoodSpeed, в том, что ошибки, будучи отключенными, не попадают в лог нет ничего странного. Я бы рекомендовал *всем* PHP разрабочикам *всегда* работать исключительно в [таком режиме](http://php.net/errorexception):

    // подключать всегда первой строкой
    function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
    }
    set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");